# Can I fail compilation based on constexpr if?

Tags: c++, static-assert

Is there a workaround to do something like this?

```
if constexpr (std::floating_point<T>) {}
else if constexpr (std::integral<T>) {}
...
else static_failure("Feature expansion needed");
```

because if I replace `static_failure` with `static_assert`, it needs the replication of all the above conditions (they are many and complicated) and it becomes ugly.

```
// It does not work properly: always fail
else static_assert(false, "Feature expansion needed");
// works fine, but it is ugly
else static_assert(std::floating_point<T> || std::integral<T> || ... || ... || ..., "Feature expansion needed");
```

I do not prefer a runtime behavior like:

```
throw "Feature expansion needed";
```

Comment: *it needs the replication of all the above conditions* What do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't need replication of all the above conditions, and you may as well use `always_false<T>` as workaround to `static_assert` issues. That's being said, you'd better put the full requirement as a requirement in the declaration of the function rather than use `static_assert` to notify that these conditions fail.

Comment: @kiner_shah Added answer to your question.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/7nGxY46h7)'s the trick. In C++23 you can just use `static_assert(false)`.

Comment: @n.m. Wow! The correct answer is yours! But g++ does not support it yet. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2593r0.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++23, you might use `static_assert(false);` in non-instantiated context.
Before, it would be ill-formed NDR, but most compiler do diagnostic on that.

```
if constexpr (std::floating_point<T>) { /*...*/ }
else if constexpr (std::integral<T>) { /*...*/ }
/*...*/
else static_assert(false, "Feature expansion needed");
```

Before C++23, you have to cheat, common legal way is with `always_false`:

```
template <typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};
```

and then

```
if constexpr (std::floating_point<T>) { /*...*/ }
else if constexpr (std::integral<T>) { /*...*/ }
/*...*/
else static_assert(always_false{}, "Feature expansion needed");
```

Comment: About C++23, unfortunately `static_assert(false, ...)` is not supported as of g++12.2.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you just need the static assert to be dependant on T and always be false like this:

```
if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {}
else
    static_assert(sizeof(T) < 0, "Only works for integral T");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Yhesd58rK

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(T) < 0);` is **pedantically** ill-formed NDR as `static_assert(false);` even if compilers fail to diagnose the former and succeed for the later.

Answer (score 3):

replace your last `if constexpr` with `static_assert`.

Instead of:

```
else if constexpr (last_case)
     //Do last case
else
     static_failure("prompt");
```

Do this:

```
else {
     static_assert(last_case,"prompt");
     //Do last case
};
```

Some proposals are made to legalize  `static_assert(false, "prompt");`, but it is not yet part of std.